# rails app breaking for IE 8

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

My rails site is completely broken in IE 8 for some reason.

These pages where I am getting the error.
[image: Error']

Here's what I have in my `application.html.erb`

```
<title></title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'mobile' if mobile_device? %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'dropzone' %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag 'malsup.jquery.form' %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.form-validator.min' %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag 'css_browser_selector' %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.screwdefaultbuttonsV2.min' %>

 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="container maindiv"> 

<img class="img-responsive book" src="/assets/book1.png">

<img class="img-responsive cup" src="/assets/cup8.png">

<div class="black_bg">

<%= render 'layouts/header' %>

<%= yield %>

<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

 </div> 

</div>
```

I am not able to rectify the issue here. After searching have tried few of the solutions like adding this script from one of the answer.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried `sass-rails` gem as well and updated my `production.rb` with below code
     `config.assets.compile = false
      config.assets.compress = true
      config.sass.style = :compressed`

But it didn't help.

Please suggest.

Comment: can you please paste the `application.js`  here

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/vjsBaD7) 

here you go.